# how to show list on keypress event in datagridview's combobox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I have a datagridview named as DGV_PO and it contains 6 columns. 1st column in Product Code and it is combobox showing all the Product Code. I want when user press any key on this column, all the list of product codes will show and user select any code and same will enter in combobox.

Comment: Just set the `DataSource` of the DataGridViewComboBoxColumn to a compatible collection (a List, a Column of a DataTable etc.). The `AutoComplete` property defaults to `true`